# Künneth theorem in étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homotopy-theory, cohomology

I am searching for an account of the Künneth theorem in étale cohomogy. Does the Künneth theorem in étale cohomology also follow from the 6-functor formalism or some other formalism?

It would be nice to see general methods for proving a Künneth theorem as well.

Comment: What do you mean by follow from a formalism? I think of the Kunneth formula as part of the formalism - i.e. the formalism consists of six functors and a bunch of natural relations between them, and (at least) one of the relations is called the Kunneth formula and implies the classical one. But the proof is still some concrete calculation. The proof and statement in general form are certainly in SGA.

Comment: The six functors formalism implies the Künneth formula for cohomology with compact support. As for cohomology itself, the formalism of universally locally acyclic (ULA) sheaves provides a general concept which leads to Künneth formulas over a field (because generically over any base, anything constructible on something of finite presentation is ULA). For a conceptual account on this kind of things, you might have a look at Hansen and Scholze's paper arXiv:2109.06766. If motivic methods also count as "general methods", there are arXiv:1905.03478 for étale motives, and arXiv:1812.06441 for SH.